# How can I continuously open websites using Watir?

Tags: ruby, safari, watir, browser-automation, safariwatir

I have an array of url strings (i.e. "http://www.cnn.com") which I want to iterate through and open in Safari using watir.

```
urlArray.each do |url|
browser.goto(url)
end
```

will open the first page, but it never proceeds to the next pages in the array.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Safariwatir is somewhat poorly supported at the moment..  Other than one patch made 5 months ago, there has not been any active development since the fall of 2010.   Have you considered maybe using chrome, firefox, or ie?  You could run any of those using watir-webdriver, and eventually (we hope, if apple ever steps up) safari once webdriver supports it.

Comment: Safari support now in Watir-webdriver.  See http://watirwebdriver.com/safari/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me, it opened both Google and Yahoo.

```
require "rubygems"
require "safariwatir"

urlArray = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com"]
browser = Watir::Safari.new
urlArray.each do |url|
  browser.goto url
end
```

When I added `"http://www.cnn.com"` to `urlArray`

```
urlArray = ["http://www.cnn.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com"]
```

it opened just cnn.com, so the problem is at that page.

Comment: Thank you very much. That definitely helps. I'm new to Watir (and Ruby in general really), so I wasn't sure if I was missing something else.